# Install / run (not: download) APK file directly from website

Tags: android, installation, apk

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328710/1469208), but -- as it claims -- link starts download of `.apk` file, while I'm looking for any way to run it, if it is installed, directly from the web.

I found [this example](https://testflightapp.com/androidsplash/) and TestFlight's webpage. There's a link `Already Installed? Launch the App` -- a simple `<a>` tag with `href` set to `testflightapp://com.testflightapp.androidapp?scheme=http&amp;host=testflightapp.com&amp;path=m/builds`.

However, it seems, that this kind of href / protocol is supported only by installed Test Flight application and not available in general in Android system.

Am I right, that my own application -- the one, that I want to run via link from website -- must itself register and handle private protocol, as in this example.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your app must have an [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) that responds to a particular (preferably non-standard) URI.

In the above case, the intent-filter is for `testflightapp://` scheme URIs.

Comment: Is this working perfectly for you? If it works will you please give me one sample, because i dont know how to do this....