# Plist file Android alternative

Tags: android, apk

I would like to have a link on web page where from mobile device I can click and Android .apk application will install (like on the Play Market). I know that in order to reach this functionality for iOS I need to have an .ipa file and a .plist XML. What do I have to do in case of Android app?

**upd:** I found this topic [apk installation from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328459/apk-installation-from-web-page) but apk only downloads to filesystem and user has to manually install it. I would like to installation process start automatically :(

Comment: Do you mean manifest file ? manifest file contains all the permissions that the app would be making use of.

Comment: So, is just manifest the alternative to plist? In other words, I can put a manifest next to apk file and everything will work properly? In addition, I have link something like follow to iOS app: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://.../some_app/app.plist` And what link I have to have in Android case?