# Auto installation apk files from web page

Tags: javascript, android, html, apk

My question is addition for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328459/apk-installation-from-web-page).
I want to install basic application set on android device after hard reset. I want to automatically install the set of apk files from web page.

Example i have a html page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function installApk() {
            var arr = ["LogMeIn.apk", "TeamViewer.apk", "Mobile Iron.apk"];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                window.open("../Software/" + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="installApk()">
<p>Example install</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's wrong. Anyone can help? Or may suggest a different solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install directly as google play does. this is anti android system

but if you want to install after google account login via your webpages than refer this https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs

Comment: if i heve link <a href="path to my .apk file">link</a>, then apk is will installed after the user select the setups program. I want to do this in an automatic mode for multiple applications. I want to use javascript function for this. Can help me with this function?

Comment: when user click on link than first apk will be downloaded in user device and than if user click on that apk than it will have prompt to install dialog...  but if you imeplement google+ in your site than user be able to install directly from your website...